What solving algorithm for a cut sum problem?
I'm looking for a solving algorithm for the following problem.
Maximize $\sum\limits_{t=1}^T [Min ( \sum\limits_{n=1}^N w(n)*P(n,t);e)]$
Subject to:
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^N w(n) = 1$
$\forall w(n)  \in [0;1]$
$e  \in ]0;1]$
$P(n,t)$ is a Matrix of constants.
The vector of w and a value for e hast to be found.
My problem is the "cut-sum" where the result of each inner sumproduct is reduced to the variable e if the sumproduct is larger then e
The main problem is a costs function to minimize with term above as divider. The solver is supposed to run over larger sets of different matrixes of constants P(n,t).
Tools I can gain access to is: R, Mathlab, Python packages...
Mainly I'm interessed in what kind of solving algorithm might be suitable and worth to take a closer look at.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

thanks for the hint to a newbie. edited.
